# Overriding Sharepoint SaveButton

Tags: 2010, custom-form, visual-web-part

Fairly new to sharepoint, and working on a project which involves making custom webparts to enable extra functionality in new/edit/display webparts.

I have a working overridden SaveButton in the webpart for the New Form, but when I try and do the same thing on the Edit form it's not firing the event.  I've tried creating seperate buttons for each form, or calling the NewSaveButton from the edit form, but neither way is working.  I've tried creating rendering templates, and that's also not working.

Does anyone have any idea's as to what I might be missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a javascript function called [PreSaveAction](http://wael-abbas.blogspot.com/2009/02/sharepoint-presaveaction.html) onto the pages the will override the Save action to allow you to run your own code.  Once your code executes, you return true or false and the item is saved or canceled.

We don't have much to go on, so this might not satisfy your requirements, but it does answer your question.

Comment: I'm more of a c# developer than a javascript one so this didn't occur to me.  I'll try this and see how I go.  Thanks :)